# Two query, two results from sql trying to divide them in php

Tags: php, mysql, division

i have two count query from the sql. I wan to divide this two query's result. i tried:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xoxo") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(xxxx) AS a zzzz";

    $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(xxxx) AS b FROM zzzz WHERE xxxx = 'cccc'";


    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error querying database');
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die('Error querying database');

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $rowa = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

    $x = $row/$rowa;

    echo $x;
```

But it tells me that it has a fatal error. i also tried:

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xoxo") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

```
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(xxxx) AS row1 FROM zzzz";

    $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(xxxx) AS row2 FROM zzzz WHERE xxxx = 'cccc'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error querying database');
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die('Error querying database');


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    }

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

    }

    echo (int)($row['row1'] / $row1['row2']);
```

but it told me that it is a division by zero. However my row1 and row2 both has value to it.

Comment: $row is visible only inside while loop,same as with $row1.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `while` loop it means it will loop until the condition is false, meaning that your `$row` and `$row1` are both false. what you need is:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(xxxx) AS row1 FROM zzzz";

$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(xxxx) AS row2 FROM zzzz WHERE xxxx = 'cccc'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error querying database');
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die('Error querying database');

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

echo (int)($row['row1'] / $row1['row2']);
```

your first example didnt work becouse when you do `$row/$rowa` you are trying to divide 2 arrays...

Comment: Remember to handle $row1['row2'] == 0 which would result in a PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

you have  initialize the result of both queries in `while loop`

try this

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

echo (int)($row['row1'] / $row1['row2']);
```